# Path for my SSIS package...where is it?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, path

I'm trying to find the exact path of where my SSIS packages are stored.  The msdb.dbo.sysssispackages folder only shows a "folderid" and a "foldername".  I'm looking for the direct path it's stored at.

Example, we house most of our ssis packages on a path such as this:

**\\servername\d$\packages**

Is there a way to get that path above using t-sql?

Comment: put that into a windows explorer and find the file name

Comment: I know how to find it with the gui/windows explorer.
I have a SSIS job that runs every morning capturing various pieces of SQL Server data from over 280+ sql servers and storing it into a database repository so I can easily query this table and get data based off of each server. My SSIS job has about 7 steps in it that run and I'd like to add this information into it as well. The table structure would look something like this: ID, Servername\Folder, DTSX Filename, Last Updated, File Size, Notes.

Comment: How to you execute the packages? Were they deployed to the server? Do you execute them through dtexec? What SQL Server version are you using?

Note: If the package had been deployed to the server (hence, you can see it in msdb.dbo.sysssispackages), it means that it resides IN THE SERVER now. So any connection that it had to the file system is meaningless now.

Comment: Ido, so what you are saying is that after import a .dtsx file into a server through integration services, I can now DELETE that .dtsx file off of the server itself because is resides in the server now?
If I can't delete it, and SQL Server needs it there to reference it....THAT'S THE PATH I NEED.
So if SQL Server is saying, "My SSIS package is imported and it's located at D:\Packages."  THAT'S the info I am looking for.  The "D:\Packages" folder.
Hopefully that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an answer totally in the wrong direction, but cant you just look at your package path in your ssis-project?

> I assume that **\servername\d$\packages** is just the folder where
>   your ssis-packages and project is.

[image]

Comment: I have a SSIS job that runs every morning capturing various pieces of SQL Server data from over 280+ sql servers and storing it into a database repository so I can easily query this table and get data based off of each server.  
My SSIS job has about 7 steps in it that run and I'd like to add this information into it as well.  The table structure would look something like this:
ID,
Servername\Folder,
DTSX Filename,
Last Updated,
File Size,
Notes.

Comment: well depending on sql server version and deployment model, the information will be either in the table you already mention, or in Integration Services Catalog. however, what i don't know is whether sqlserver actually stores the packages on the file system, or somewhere in the database. 

what is your goal here, not sure i got that

Comment: I'm creating a repository of sql server information of our nearly 300 servers.  What this will include is a table that will store the server name, the path where all the DTSX files are stored for that server (it's not uniformed which bothers me but that's another story) and if they exist, the name of the DTSX file, when it was last updated and the file size.  So my sql statement could be something like this, "Select * from ssispackageinfo where servername = 'ServerNameHere'. The results would show the server name, the path, the file names of all in that path, last time it was updated and size.